# How to fix "Main is not defined at..." problem

Tags: lighthouse

I have recently run a scan/test on Web.Dev for my website, a link. The scan ended up identifying a browser error. The scan results say the following:

> Browser errors were logged to the console
>   Errors logged to the console indicate unresolved problems. They can come from network request failures and other browser concerns.

Can you please help me solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue. A plug-in called simple share was causing the problem. The Autoptomize was caching its .js file. After I included the file in the Autoptomize's exclusion list, the problem got resolved.